# Perl v5.16 rejected when only v5.10 is required

Tags: perl, version

I recently installed [Strawberry Portable Version of Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html). The web site says it's v5.16.

I used CPAN to install [`Marpa::PP`](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Marpa%3a%3aPP). It installed successfully. Then I used a sample program to test `Marpa::PP`.  When I tried to run this, I got the following error:

```
Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.0, stopped at perl/site/lib/Marpa/PP.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at perl/site/lib/Marpa/PP.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at F:\workdir\perl\perl32\sql_insert.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at F:\workdir\perl\perl32\sql_insert.pl line 1.
```

When I run `perl -v`, I get:

```
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 0 (v5.16.0) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
```

Please help me to make sense out of it.  My perl is v5.16, the error says it is only v5.8 and the [code in Marpa/PP.pm line 18](https://metacpan.org/source/JKEGL/Marpa-PP-0.014000/lib/Marpa/PP.pm#L18) has `use 5.010`. I think this is creating the problem. Also, please suggest what should I do to make it work.

Comment: Is this the only perl in your system. Somehow i feel you have at least 2 of them...

Comment: The `perl` that was executed by `perl -v` and the `perl` you use to execute your script are different builds of Perl. You didn't specify how you launched the Perl you used to execute your script. I suspect your have file associations you want to change.

Comment: you need to change a `PATH` variable to use one version of `perl`

Answer (score 3):

You've got multiple versions of Perl installed.

Where you ran `perl -v`, run `which perl` to get to full path to it.

Now, open up the script that complains it is Perl 5.8. Check the first line of it, the "shebang line". Edit to match the result of the `which perl` command, and it should start being run by Perl 5.16, assuming the script was started by the shell.

If you are using some "click to run" Windows system, you may have some more work to do to associate the ".pl" extension with the new path to perl you found above.

Comment: There are indeed two perls on the system. I was able to solve the issue by giving the location of correct perl.exe explicitly in the command line for running perl.